# React native - Calendar type

Tags: ios, react-native, calendar, tcomb-form-native

In react native app, i'm having a native datepicker component which uses the same calendar type as the device calendar type.

For ios device there are more calendar types Gregorian ,buddhist calendar..etc.

For example if user default device calendar type selected is buddhist calendar and in app it uses the same type. But i need app 
to always use the Gregorian calendar type regardless of the device calendar type.

Anyone please help me with this problem, Thanks.
[image]

Edited

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide more specific or detail easily people understand what you wish to get the answer. Or upload any image to show your purpose as well.

Comment: @Seyha image added for reference, do have any idea

Comment: U can change locale of timezones before u call DatePicker. Did u use any plugin or DatePickerIOS?

Comment: U can use moment.js to help it...
Example:
import moment from 'moment' import 'moment/locale/pt-br' moment.locale('pt-BR')